# JFrame is not visible

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, jframe, windows-services

JFrame is not visible when the initial caller is a servlet running on Tomcat that runs as a Windows service.

Apache Tomcat 5 is configured to run as a Windows service. A servlet which runs on this Tomcat server calls batch file `script.bat`. This batch file executes a JAR that has class `MyClass.java` which creates the JFrame.

However, the JFrame is visible when called in these ways:

- directly from command prompt
- when Tomcat is started normally - not as a Windows service

Code used in Servlet to call script.bat:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start /path/to/script.bat");
```

**Contents of script.bat**

```
@echo on
SET CP=.;path/to/some.jar
java -cp %CP% com.package.MyClass %1
```

**Contents of MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass {
  public void showFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My JFrame");
    // ...
    frame.setSize(360, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    new MyClass().showFrame();
  }
}
```

**Java Version:** 1.5.0_11-b03 (32bit)

**Tomcat Version:** 5.5 (32bit)

Comment: Windows services don’t tend to be allowed a “window” - I’m not sure of the technical aspects, I’m just aware that they are normally permitted a “window”

Comment: [This might help explain it better](http://javaservice.ow2.org/docs/v1docs/faq.html#gui)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The JFrame is created by another JVM which starts up when the batch file is executed, so the JFrame in my case is not created by the windows service directly.

Comment: If the Windows service is running the batch file, then the window is been created under the context of the service, it's the same thing

Comment: Thank you. I've understood now. I tried calling mspaint.exe in a similar way. The application was not visible but Task Manager showed that Paint was running.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there any way to JFrame GUI App run as a service in Windows?

Comment: @kieuanhvu No - as far as I remember, Window services don't have windows - they also run under a different "user"/permission level